# Facebook events api access 2018 access restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I currently use the Facebook API to access their events endpoint via a web application.

I am aware of the access restrictions that they put in place.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

My questions are:

1) When I ping the API I do not get an access denied response, but rather a 2xx with no events. I wanted to see if access has in fact been restricted to read a group's events based on the response that I'm getting and is it just possible that the API has changed?

2) Is anyone aware of when they are going to resume reviewing apps and how to have existing API access reviewed?

Comment: Yes, an empty response is what you should expect right now. They probably decided to not issue an error message, to do the least damage to currently running apps. (Just “no data” is something every app should be able to handle - if only implicitly, because any loop over the results will just loop zero times then; proper error handling however is something a lot of people might have rather neglected.)

Comment: @CBroe An error would have been way better in my case. My code treated the empty array as those events have been deleted from FB. An error would have prevented me from marking every event for deletion.