# Facebook developer / user_events

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've seen the Facebook announcement this morning. I've also seen that there is a 3.0 API and that old apps need to be reviewed and that new apps can now be reviewed. I'm trying to finish a new app but 'me/events/not_replied' still doesn't seem to work and returns an empty array whether using API 3.0 or API 2.12.

Is it working for you ?

Thank you

Comment: I asked the same question here essentially, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943475/facebook-events-api-access-2018-access-restrictions, any luck being able to submit? When I go to submit I do not see the events api as an option in the list of services to check off.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#events-4-4

> GET /events — You can no longer get the following edges:
>
> ...
>
> - noreply
>
> ...

It is not possible anymore, not with any API version.

Comment: I have just tried and I cannot even see a public event I have created using "/me/events/created" - and actually, if I cannot access "not_replied" events, the API is no longer of interest to me (aggregator website) since it would mean that each organizer who creates events on Facebook would have to use my APP.

Comment: i believe the events api is still not available. anyway, the endpoints for users (attending, noreply, ..) are gone for good and they will not come back, because you were able to get names of users who did not authorize your app.

Comment: 6 days later and I still cannot see any change. /me/events or /me/events/created requests still return an empty array event though I have created a test event. Is it the same for you ?